# Print only recent file

Tags: perl

I want to print only the recent file in a repertory.

My script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#use strict;
#use warnings;

@files = <'/mnt/SESSIONS*'>;
foreach $file (@files) {
  print $file . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
/mnt/SESSIONS2018-12-18_14_00.log
/mnt/SESSIONS2018-12-18_14_15.log
/mnt/SESSIONS2018-12-18_14_30.log
/mnt/SESSIONS2018-12-18_14_45.log
/mnt/SESSIONS2018-12-18_15_00.log
```

I want only recent file name which is `/mnt/SESSIONS2018-12-18_15_00.log`.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: sort them and take the last one?

Comment: (OT: *Always* `use strict; use warnings;`!)

Comment: yes, i use use strict; use warnings

Comment: @dfgert No. No, you don’t.

Comment: i have this message with use strict and warning Global symbol "@files" requires explicit package name at test.pl line 40.
BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at test.pl line 40.

Comment: @dfgert https://qntm.org/files/perl/perl.html

Comment: The `-M` file file test will give you a numeric value relative to when the file was last modified that can be sorted on to find the latest file.

Comment: @JGNI where i will should put thr option -M ?

Comment: Change your loop code to `print( (sort {-M $a <=> -M $b } @files) [0])`

Comment: @JGNI i put but its blocked

Comment: @dfgert I don't understand you. If you are getting an error message then please post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want...  if you can take for granted that the filename will always be in order of when it was created, then something like this will work:

```
my @files = <'/mnt/SESSIONS*'>;
my $latest;

foreach my $file (@files) {
  $latest = $file if $file gt $latest;
}

print $latest;
```

Or, if you want to go based on when the last file was modified (ignoring filenames), you could do this:

```
my @files = <'/mnt/SESSIONS*'>;
my @latest = (undef, undef);

foreach my $file (@files) {
  my $mod = -M $file;
  if (!$latest[1] or $mod < $latest[1]) {
    @latest = ($file, $mod);
  }
}

print $latest[0];
```

Nothing against a sort, but a sort is average case O(n log n), whereas this approach is O(n) and will guarantee only one traversal of all files.  Granted, the number of files in a directory will unlikely be so great as to impact performance, but this is a consideration.

Alternatively, if you just want to make a system call, you can do this:

```
ls -A1t /mnt/SESSIONS* | head -1
```

Comment: keep in mind that quite often you are going to be exchanging code readability for tiny increments in performance - for instance, in this case, if you have 100_000 items in your list, the sort will take about 11 times more time than just doing the gt, but we are talking about microseconds (if not nanoseconds), while the code gets harder to understand (assuming you are a bit familiar with Perl or similar syntaxes).

Comment: Yes, that's a reasonable statement.  Readabiliy and maintainability should always factor into which approach one takes.  I tend to over-optimize for the sake of those nanoseconds, so your comment is quite fair.

Answer (score 2):

The previous suggestions in the comments refer you to -M operator/function, which returns (a definition of) the modification time of a file - that assumes that the files are modified only while they are used than never changed after that.

The way you state your problem suggests that you want the file that is named with the latest name - and that makes it faster to just use the information you already have in memory, which is the names themselves.

```
my ($latest) = sort { $b cmp $a } @files;
print "$latest\n";
```

the things referred to and that you may want to read a bit more about are:

- -M (and the other file functions): https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html
- sort: https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html
- cmp and <=> : https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators